# Re enable click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some paging features that I've written.  What I'm trying to do is when user gets to the end of the paging results display End of records.  When the back link is click then the paging is re enabled allowing the user the option to either click next or back based on where they currently are.  Right now I have it the user can flip through the pages until the end.  The message is displayed and then they can click back to the beginning.  Problem is when they click next I can not get the link reactivated.  I've tried the jquery on / off and also the enabled disabled attributes.  I'm sure there is a better way but for now this is what I'm starting out with.  Thank you in advance.

Here is the code going forward

```
    $('#Next').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    currentPageNumber += 1;
    if (currentPageNumber == 1) {
        $('.pageNumber').text(currentPageNumber);
        $("#displayMe").empty();
        loadData(currentPageNumber);
    }
    else {
        $("#displayMe").empty();
        $('.pageNumber').text(currentPageNumber);
        loadData(currentPageNumber);
    }
    if (currentPageNumber == maxPage) {
        $(this).html("End of Records");
        $(this).off('click');                      
    }

});
```

Here is the code to go backwards:

```
    $('#Back').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()        
    currentPageNumber -= 1;
    if (currentPageNumber < maxPage) {
        $("#Next").html("Next 5 >>");
        $('#Next').on('click');
        $('.pageNumber').text(currentPageNumber);
        $("#displayMe").empty();
        loadData(currentPageNumber);            
    }

});
```

Comment: it would seem that you are attaching the click event listener to '#Next' but you are not running any code when the event is invoked

Comment: Why remove and re-add the click handler in the first place?  It would be much easier to just add a condition early in the click handler (immediately after `e.preventDefault();` but before incrementing the page number - `if(currentPageNumber == maxPage) return;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$(this).off('click');` after reaching the last page, the click event is unbound from the element and is no longer available. http://api.jquery.com/off/.

The problem is when you call `$('#Next').on('click');` you are only passing in the name of the event and no function to execute. When you use `.on()` you must pass the name of the event and a function to execute. http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Try something like

```
function myClickEvent(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    currentPageNumber += 1;
    if (currentPageNumber == 1) {
        $('.pageNumber').text(currentPageNumber);
        $("#displayMe").empty();
        loadData(currentPageNumber);
    }
    else {
        $("#displayMe").empty();
        $('.pageNumber').text(currentPageNumber);
        loadData(currentPageNumber);
    }
    if (currentPageNumber == maxPage) {
        $(this).html("End of Records");
        $(this).off('click');                      
    }
}
```

Attach the event to #Next

```
$('#Next').on('click', myClickEvent);
```

To enable the click event again

```
$('#Back').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()        
    currentPageNumber -= 1;
    if (currentPageNumber < maxPage) {
        $("#Next").html("Next 5 >>");
        $('#Next').on('click', myClickEvent);
        $('.pageNumber').text(currentPageNumber);
        $("#displayMe").empty();
        loadData(currentPageNumber);            
    }
```

Comment: While this does fix the problem, it is not good coding (on the OP's part).  Clicking back multiple times is going to add the same click event to the next button multiple times.

Comment: Good catch, it would be better to bind the event to the back button if the click event does not exist, or if currentPageNumber == maxPage.

Answer (score 1):

Store the click function in a variable and use it for on and off bindings like:

```
var fnNext = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    currentPageNumber += 1;
    if (currentPageNumber == 1) {
        $('.pageNumber').text(currentPageNumber);
        $("#displayMe").empty();
        loadData(currentPageNumber);
    }
    else {
        $("#displayMe").empty();
        $('.pageNumber').text(currentPageNumber);
        loadData(currentPageNumber);
    }
    if (currentPageNumber == maxPage) {
        $(this).html("End of Records");
        $(this).off('click');                      
    }
}
```

and use this of on and off:
 $('#Next').on('click', fnNext);

```
 $('#Back').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()        
    currentPageNumber -= 1;
    if (currentPageNumber < maxPage) {
        $("#Next").html("Next 5 >>");
        $('#Next').on('click', fnNext);
        $('.pageNumber').text(currentPageNumber);
        $("#displayMe").empty();
        loadData(currentPageNumber);            
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace this with your last if statement with this.

```
if (currentPageNumber < maxPage) {
        $("#Next").html("Next 5 >>");
        $('#Next').click (function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.pageNumber').text(currentPageNumber);
          $("#displayMe").empty();
          loadData(currentPageNumber);   
        }
}
```